# test nonprofit rates in PayPal sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

On developer.paypal.com where I can create test accounts, is there any way of specifying that a particular business account is a nonprofit so that I can test making donations at the [2.2% nonprofit rate](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/donations) instead of the standard 2.9% rate?

For example, when I make a test donation of $20, I want `mc_gross` to be `20.00` and `mc_fee` to be `0.74`, not `0.88`.

Answer (score 1):

No, last I checked with PayPal MTS it couldn't be done -- at least, not easily on their end.

Fortunately it's not hard to work around this and I'm pretty sure you can come up with something workable.